# How to get data by using full text indexing in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, indexing

I am using this laravel package for searching

https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable

This package use query something like that

```
"select `id`, `name` from (select `customers`.*, max((case when LOWER(`customers`.`name`) LIKE ? then 15 else 0 end) + (case when LOWER(`customers`.`name`) LIKE ? then 5 else 0 end) + (case when LOWER(`customers`.`name`) LIKE ? then 1 else 0 end) + (case when LOWER(`customers`.`id`) LIKE ? then 30 else 0 end) + (case when LOWER(`customers`.`id`) LIKE ? then 10 else 0 end) + (case when LOWER(`customers`.`id`) LIKE ? then 2 else 0 end)) as relevance from `customers` group by `customers`.`id` having relevance >= 1.50 order by `relevance` desc) as `customers` limit 10"
```

I have done indexing on columns on which I am searching but indexing is not implemented

This is how I am searching

```
Customer::select('id','name')->search($request->keyword, null, true)->limit(10)->get();
```

Comment: That sort of query the package is doing is probably not able to use indexes. You might instead want to use MySQL supported [full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: I recommend using [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scout) for full text search of Eloquent models. That package is mantained till the latest version of Laravel and has proper integration.

Comment: Laravel scount works fine without algolia?

Answer (score 0):

Why You just use Laravel Scout. It provide it officially and can be integrated with Agolia or TNTsearch indexing services. After using you can index them by SQLlite or Agolia

Comment: Because algolia is very much expensive